# Java memory as reported with JMX vs. htop

Tags: java, linux, memory

I'm trying to debug why a program which prints `Hello` and then `Thread.sleep(3600*1000)` uses ~404MB of virtual memory under linux (with both OpenJDK and Sun JVMs) on both CentOS 5 and Ubuntu 10.04 server. (a MediaTemple (dv) and (ve), respectively).

But more specifically, when I connect using VisualVM or JConsole I see what looks like  reasonable memory usage: 820KM heap (after GC); 8.4MB PermGen; 1136 classes loaded.

Why the discrepancy?

Is purely having a JVM running using that much memory?  I tried starting two Hello apps to see if the memory usage scales linearly, and it does:

I started with 78MB of total RAM used. Starting one hello app bumps the memory usage to 376MB. Starting another hello app gives a total RAM usage of 656MB, so memory doesn't seem to be shared well. (these numbers are not virtual memory

(these specific numbers are with OpenJDK, but using the Sun 6 JDK gives comprable, but slightly lower memory usage)

Code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("HI");
        Thread.sleep(3600 * 1000);
        return;
    }
}
```

Command Line:

```
java -Xmx32m -Xms32m Hello
```

With JMX:

```
 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8005 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xmx32m -Xms32m Hello
```

Thank you for your help,

Wiktor

Comment: To clarify: RES memory for Hello is 21MB (as expected) and SHR memory is 8MB. Both reasonable (well, for Java ;-)). My problem is that the virtual memory usage is subtracted from my total allowance of 2GB, and I need to run ~18 java applications.

Comment: I tried using `ulimit -v` to adjust virtual memory usage, but unless it's set to about 400,000 (400MB) the java app does not start successfully.

Comment: I tried using -Djava.awt.headless=true (with both Sun and OpenJDK) without significant effect.

Comment: For giggles I tried using gcj, which still reports 84MB used, but crucially memory usage no longer scales linearly. One hello app increases memory usage from 78MB to 119MB, starting another app increases to 137MB. Much more reasonable. (it's the scaling I really care about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heap is only one of the memory areas that Java uses.

See [Section 3.5 in the Java Virtual Machine Specification Overview](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html)

The PermGen is another one that you can specify how much Java is allowed to use.

Each thread has a virtual machine stack, which you also limit the size of.

There is a Code Cache, or Method Area to store the compiled code.

There are possibly native method stacks.

Memory mapped files, or portions of files (such as indexes of jar file), take up part of the process's (non heap) memory area.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you answered my question. Sadly it doesn't quite solve my problem, but that's for another post.

Comment: Good examples of where memory may go.  However are there any concrete steps to get a breakdown of _precisely_ where the memory is in a Sun / OpenJDK java process?

Comment: Section 3.5 maps to section 2.5 in the JVM 7 spec.