# Linux configurations that would affect Java memory usage?

Tags: java, linux, memory

---

Background:

I have a set of java background workers I start as part of my webapp. I develop locally on Ubuntu 10.10 and deploy to an Ubuntu 10.04LTS server (a media temple (ve) instance).

They're both running the same JVM: `Sun JVM 1.6.0_22-b04`. As part of the initialization script each worker is started with explicit `Xmx`, `Xms`, and `XX:MaxPermGen` settings.

Yet somehow locally all 10 workers use 250MB, while on the server they use more than 2.7GB.

I don't know how to begin to track this down. I thought the Ubuntu (and thus, kernel) version might make a difference, but I tried an old 10.04 VM and it behaves as expected.

I've noticed that the machine does not seem to ever use memory for buffer or cache (according to `htop`), which seems a bit strange, but perhaps normal for a server?

---

(edited)
Some info:

```
(server)
root@devel:/app/axir/target# uname -a
Linux devel 2.6.18-028stab069.5 #1 SMP Tue May 18 17:26:16 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(local)
wiktor@beastie:~$ uname -a
Linux beastie 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

(edited)
Comparing PS output: (`ps -eo "ppid,pid,cmd,rss,sz,vsz"`)

```
PPID   PID CMD                           RSS    SZ         VSZ
(local)
1588  1615 java -cp axir-distribution.   25484 234382    937528
1615  1631 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   83472 163059    652236
1615  1657 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   70624  89135    356540
1615  1658 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   37652  77625    310500
1615  1669 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   38096  77733    310932
1615  1675 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   37420  61395    245580
1615  1684 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   38000  77736    310944
1615  1703 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   39180  78060    312240
1615  1712 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   38488  93882    375528
1615  1719 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   38312  77874    311496
1615  1726 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   38656  77958    311832
1615  1727 java -cp /home/wiktor/Code/   78016  89429    357716

(server)
22522 23560 java -cp axir-distribution.  24860  285196  1140784
23560 23585 java -cp /app/axir/target/a 100764  161629   646516
23560 23667 java -cp /app/axir/target/a  72408   92682   370728
23560 23670 java -cp /app/axir/target/a  39948   97671   390684
23560 23674 java -cp /app/axir/target/a  40140   81586   326344
23560 23739 java -cp /app/axir/target/a  39688   81542   326168
```

They look very similar. In fact, the question now is why, if I add up the virtual memory usage on the server (3.2GB) does it more closely reflect 2.4GB of memory used (according to `free`), yet locally the virtual memory used adds up to a much more substantial 4.7GB but only actually uses ~250MB. It seems that perhaps memory isn't being shared as aggressively. (if that's even possible)

Thank you for your help,

Wiktor

Comment: Yes, but so is the local client.

Comment: is java class data sharing working in both environments?  Try running with java -Xshare:on to make sure it is.  also, run jmap against your jvms to see how the memory is mapped inside; maybe there are dynamic libs on your server that for whatever reason are jumbo sized.

Comment: Hmm. Weird, if I try using `-Xshare:on` on either locally or on the server I get the message:


    Class data sharing is inconsistent with other specified options.
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    Unable to use shared archive.

<br>
I used VisualVM to look at the running process, and it's quite unspectacular. Earlier I posted about how running a few "hello world" apps at the same time uses up all my memory, yet JMX gives normal numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893061/java-memory-as-reported-with-jmx-vs-htop (820KB heap; 8.4MB PermGen) 
<br>
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know on server 'java -server' option is default, maybe this brings this problem. Try to run with -server option on client

Comment: Ah, good idea. I modified my run script locally to add the `-server` option amongst the arguments. But it doesn't seem to have had any effect. I likewise tried running with '-client' on the server with no effect as well.

Comment: Maybe you can check the differences of two VM with `jconsole` (JMX) VM settings on VM Summary tab.

Comment: Hmm. They're pretty much on par with each other.  After GC they both use about 3MB of RAM; they both have 22 threads; PermGen is 15.7MB; the only apparent difference is one has 2,106 classes loaded (server), 0 shared; the other has 2,093 classes loaded (local), 0 shared. Under "System properties" the only differences (I ran a diff) is `os.version`, `sun.jnu.encoding`, `user.dir`, `user.home`, `user.name`, and `user.timezone`, none of which seem significant.